# Why the green LED is not blinking properly on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Arch Linux ARM from USB?

Tags: activity-led

After installing Arch Linux ARM on Raspberry Pi 3 model B, everything is working as expected but the green LED that indicates the SD card read write activity. The LED just blinks every second for 0.1 seconds and continues.

After installation, I did change the kernel printk otherwise it would show thousands of messages in any tty which is bad while installation. The  `/etc/sysctl.d/20-quiet-printk.conf` goes as follows:

`kernel.printk = 7 4 1 7`

`cat /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger` produces the following output:

`none rfkill-any rfkill-none kbd-scrolllock kbd-numlock kbd-capslock kbd-kanalock kbd-shiftlock kbd-altgrlock kbd-ctrllock kbd-altlock kbd-shiftllock kbd-shiftrlock kbd-ctrlllock kbd-ctrlrlock usb-gadget usb-host timer oneshot heartbeat backlight gpio cpu cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 activity default-on transient flash torch input panic netdev mmc1 [mmc0] rfkill0`

How can I fix the LED blinking issue?

Comment: What does `cat /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger` output? How about `grep "dtparam=act_led*" /boot/config.txt`?

Comment: It gives the following output:

none rfkill-any rfkill-none kbd-scrolllock kbd-numlock kbd-capslock kbd-kanalock kbd-shiftlock kbd-altgrlock kbd-ctrllock kbd-altlock kbd-shiftllock kbd-shiftrlock kbd-ctrlllock kbd-ctrlrlock usb-gadget usb-host timer oneshot heartbeat backlight gpio cpu cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 activity default-on transient flash torch input panic netdev mmc1 [mmc0] rfkill0

Comment: OK, so the LED is setup to trigger on `mmc0` (indicated by the square brackets) so should be indicating SD card activity. As a test try `echo heartbeat | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger`, should change to a double-flash "heartbeat" pattern.

Comment: But it doesn't work with SD cards.

BTW, I am now using USB to boot for the time being. Is there a way I can add the /dev/sda2 to there?

Comment: Booting from an mmc doesn't work either. I always have that light flashing in a specific interval for some strange reason!

Comment: Yup the heartbeat pattern works fine!

Comment: Well, after rebooting, and adding usb-host, it is blinking in the heart beat pattern and sometimes blinks 3 times.
I am currently having no xorg/wayland kinds of things, I just use it as a small home server...

Comment: The LED controller is obviously working so I've no idea why `mmc0` would not be working as you expect or how you'd go about getting it to show activity for other disks. I think you can create your own LED status triggers but they live in the kernel so might be too much of a stretch and is beyond the original question. Documentation on the available triggers is a little sparse as well so choosing one based on the name is sometimes pot-luck! https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/leds/leds-class.txt https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.19.y/drivers/leds/trigger